# If only bad closed questions are holding a tag in place, what do I do?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

I've been cleaning up a bunch of small tags, and am encountering a problem with closed questions. Often, closed questions do belong under these niche tags, even though the tags shouldn't exist (e.g. [organizing](/questions/tagged/organizing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717/organizing-documents) question).

If closed questions, properly tagged for content, but not good questions for SO, are holding a tag from being deleted, should I edit the tags out of the question?

Similarly, there are questions whose tags are relevant, but which are bad questions for SO. Should the tags be edited out to let the bad tag die?

**Edit:** Looks like I'm going going to be able to take care of all of [organizing](/questions/tagged/organizing) tonight. I'm about to run out of flags. There are only five questions left, though; someone else mind finishing it off quickly? Whoever finishes this job should flag [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168330/burninate-request-organizing) for [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, just remove the tag (or come to meta and ask for help cleaning it up).

That tag looks pretty useless to me, I wouldn't mind removing it from open questions as well.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000871/i-really-need-help-organizing-my-websites-files) is a pretty rife repository of non-constructive tags. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: Good point :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176095/lets-clean-up-organization