# Let's clean up the [*organization] tags!

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

We currently have these organization-related tags: [organization](/questions/tagged/organization) [code-organization](/questions/tagged/code-organization) [project-organization](/questions/tagged/project-organization) [file-organization](/questions/tagged/file-organization)[self-organization](/questions/tagged/self-organization) [organizing](/questions/tagged/organizing)

1. Do we really need any of these tags?
2. Many of these tags have a lot of NC/OT questions in them. We probably need to clean these up.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I _do_ think that we need to clear the close votes queue though as having your close votes expire because it's been too long is fairly frustrating when trying to close not constructive questions.

Comment: I think such a tag is useful, but only one. How to structure a code-base or project or repo is an important issue. Maybe have the others map onto `organization` rather than remove them entirely.